# Read open graph image through Facebook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

Here's stackoverflow.com's og:image meta tag:

```
<meta property="og:image" itemprop="image primaryImageOfPage" content="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=ea71a5211a91&a" />
```

Is it possible to read this information through Facebook's Open Graph API, rather than scraping the page manually?

https://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://stackoveflow.com returns:

```
{
  "og_object": {
    "id": "10150180465825637",
    "description": "Q&A for professional and enthusiast programmers",
    "title": "Stack Overflow",
    "type": "website",
    "updated_time": "2015-07-21T12:33:38+0000",
    "url": "http://stackoverflow.com/"
  },
  "share": {
    "comment_count": 4,
    "share_count": 32367
  },
  "id": "http://stackoverflow.com"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you additionally request the `picture` fields, you should get the desired result:

```
/?id=http://stackoverflow.com&fields=id,share,og_object{id,title,type,updated_time,url,picture}
```

returns

```
{
  "id": "http://stackoverflow.com",
  "share": {
    "comment_count": 4,
    "share_count": 32367
  },
  "og_object": {
    "id": "10150180465825637",
    "title": "Stack Overflow",
    "type": "website",
    "updated_time": "2015-07-21T12:33:38+0000",
    "url": "http://stackoverflow.com/",
    "picture": {
      "data": {
        "is_silhouette": false,
        "url": "https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/safe_image.php?d=AQA6I9bpNGiU11fN&w=200&h=200&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcdn.sstatic.net%2Fstackoverflow%2Fimg%2Fapple-touch-icon%402.png%3Fv%3Dea71a5211a91%26a&crop"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Excellent. Thanks. :)

(I used field 'image' rather than 'picture' to get the original open graph image url, which was in larger format.)